# Single word for a 'repeat patient', as a returning visitor

Tags: single-word-requests

If a patient is discharged and then returns later to a clinic or a hospital, is there a single word we can use to describe them?

"This is not his first visit.  Mr. Jones is a _______."

Comment: Recheck, if it is for the same condition.

Comment: I suppose there might be a few different single words, depending on the reason for the return. If they are returning due to a relapse, or for a checkup, or for recovery therapy, then there may be different words that could fit.

Comment: well, if you want to pull his chains a bit you can call him a 'recidivist' ... repeat offender criminal

Comment: 'chronic' is a word often used in medicine, and if you didn't mind being a bit rude and snarky (and perhaps wanted to infer some lack of self care on the patients part) you might call him a "chronic case" ... it would be rude though

Comment: Isn;t it the other way round? Are there not *new patients* and everyone else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of his visit there matters.

To consult after treatment - follow up patient or recheck.

For treatments or consultation, while staying outside - outpatient.

To thank the doctor - grateful visitor.

To censure the doctor - vengeful visitor.

No purpose - wanderer, rover, wayfarer, crazy person, etc.

However, you could say someone is a **regular** if they visit the hospital often, whatever the reason may be.

Comment: @WS2 I hate to say but I'm a regular at a hospital. It is sure sad to be a regular at a hospital, especially if you're being operated upon all the time. I'll include that in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I will delete that. It was a bit thoughtless of me.